# Spring data JPA JPQL Select Where on child property

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I want select Mangas with list of Chapter by Date Realese.

But that query dont return the date correctly.

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM Mangas m JOIN m.chapter c where c.release= '2018-07-30' GROUP BY m.id ORDER BY c.manga.id")
    public List<MangasEntity> buscarTodos();
```

I have Domain

```
Mangas > List<Chapter>

@Entity
public class Mangas {

 //id, name, status, date

 @OneToMany
 private List<Chapters> Chapters;

 //Getter and Setter

@Entity   
public class Chapters {

    //id, release, chapterNumber

 @ManyToOne
 @JsonIgnore
 public Mangas manga;
```

My query don´t return the list of chapter by the release correctly. I want the chapter by release `2018-07-30`.

```
[
    {
        "id": 12,            
        "name": "ONE PIECE",
        "status": "COMPLETE",
        "date": 2020,            
        "Chapters": [
            {
                "id": 22,
                "release": "2018-07-30",
                "chapterNumber": 777
            },
            {
                "id": 23,
                "release": "2018-07-30",
                "chapterNumber": 253
            },
            {
                "id": 26,
                "release": "2018-07-29",
                "chapterNumber": 777
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: I think your query is equivalent to `SELECT m FROM Mangas m where m.chapters.release= '2018-07-30' ORDER BY manga.id`
So you get the mangas that have a chapter with the release day you want - but you get the whole manga, not just the chapter you're interested in.  I don't know of a way to do what you want the way you want to - you could try declaring your association as lazy, then using a "fetch join" to get just the chapters you want?

Comment: I found the solution using `Join Fetch` to return correct Chapter release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved using `JOIN FETCH`.

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT m FROM Mangas m JOIN FETCH m.chapter c WHERE c.release = '2018-07-30' GROUP BY c.id")
```

Return Manga with `List<Chapters>` by the Release

```
[
    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "ONE PIECE",
        "status": "COMPLETO",
        "date": 2020,
        "Chapters": [
            {
                "id": 22,
                "release": "2018-07-30",
                "chapterNumber": 777
            },
            {
                "id": 23,
                "release": "2018-07-30",
                "chapterNumber": 253
            }
        ]
    }
]
```